# Why can't Travis-CI find my cocoapod dependencies?

Tags: cocoapods, travis-ci

This Podspec fails on the line `pod 'SwiftyTimer', '~> 1.4'` with `Unable to find a specification for SwiftyTimer`. It installs fine locally.

**Things I've tried:**

- Specify the exact URL for SwiftyTimer (Still can't find it)
- Manually integrate SwiftyTimer (it just fails on my next dependency, and I'd really like to not completely give up on the concept of dependencies)

My Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'CWNotificationBanner_Example' do
  pod 'SwiftyTimer', '~> 1.4'
  pod 'CWNotificationBanner', :path => '../'

  target 'CWNotificationBanner_Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'Quick', '~> 0.8'
    pod 'Nimble', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'FBSnapshotTestCase'
    pod 'Nimble-Snapshots'
  end
end
```

My travis.yml:

```
language: objective-c

podfile: Example/Podfile
before_install:
 - rvm install ruby-2.2.2 #cocoapods 1.0.0 requirement not yet supported ootb by travis
 - gem install cocoapods # Since Travis is not always on latest version
 - pod install --project-directory=Example
script:
 - set -o pipefail && xctool test -workspace Example/CWNotificationBanner.xcworkspace -scheme CWNotificationBanner-Example -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | xcpretty
 - pod lib lint
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer turned out to be: Specify an xcode version in the `osx_image` key in my .travis.yml:

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.3
xcode_workspace: Example/CWNotificationBanner.xcworkspace
xcode_scheme: CWNotificationBanner-Example
xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator9.3
podfile: Example/Podfile
```

Comment: in my case i've to put an `pod repo update` before installing pods

Answer (score 5):

You might need to do a `pod repo update` to ensure that the Podspec is in the up-to-date repo.

Comment: Thanks! It's been running for about 45 min now… hopefully this won't happen every time?

Comment: Failed after 48 minutes. Take 2 now running.

Comment: Nope: gives a 4MB log file and then keels over. Any other ideas? :/

Answer (score 1):

In my case it happened because of lack of pod specification on the CI machine. To fix it you need to add `before_install` in `travis.yml` file:

```
before_install:
  - pod repo update
```